# How to vertically align text of VBox.label property in Flex 3?

Tags: flex3

How to vertically align text of VBox `label` property in Flex 3?
At this time I can change it only if  I apply this CSS style:

```
LinkButton{
   paddingTop: -2;
}
```

But applying this style affects many other components. Is there any other way?

Comment: Could you post your code? I tried to reconstruct your issue by using TabNavigator and two VBoxes but this style didn't help me.